# Why Should You Store Data in a Variable Before Using it?

Tags: python, variables, parameters, parameter-passing

So whenever I look at code examples, I constantly see:

```
myNum = 12
def func(var):
    return var
myReturn = func(myNum)
print myReturn
```

instead of:

```
myNum = 12
def func(var):
    return var
print func(myNum)
```

The only reason I could think you would use the first one is to diverge from possible confusion (if they don't know what that function/method does (that doesn't work with this example since they can see the function)), but you could counter that with a comment saying what is going on.

And, although fractionally tiny, using another variable uses RAM and clutters your code with variables that could have not been defined and the code could have worked perfectly fine.

It is simply convention? Or is it really just personal preference?

Comment: Either works, the first because someone may use `myReturn` to do something else.  Imagine `int x; x=doSomething(); if(x > ...) { ...}`  That is now I have x and I can use x to compare, or call another method, or test a condition, etc.

Comment: Typically, you're not going to be using `print` in your code and you're going to want to use the return value of a function.

Comment: @JonH, OK, that's what I thought. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Scoutdrago3 - I'll add it as an answer if it helped.

Comment: @o_o yeah, I only printed to make a quick example. But it'd work the same way if I were to use the value itself, as well.

Comment: @JonH, I mean if there really is no other reason, yeah, go for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either works, the first because someone may use `myReturn` to do something else.

Imagine the following chunk of code:

`int x; x=doSomething(); if(x > ...) {//more code doMoreWithX(x);}`

That is now I have `x` and I can use `x` to compare, or call another method, or test a condition, etc.  In this case you need some sort of reference back to what your original method did.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is so short and simple that it doesn't matter there.  To some extent it is a matter of style.  To some extent it is a matter of readability.  If the expressions in the statement were long or complicated then writing separate simpler and shorter expressions can make the code easier to read and easier to avoid errors.  Giving a name to the expression can also help to communicate why it exists and what purpose it serves.  Also, it is very useful for the line where an exception is raised to be a short and simple expression so that you can easily see which part of the expression was at fault.  It can also help when debugging since you can see each of the local variables in the debugger, and change their values.